# What runtime debugging/introspection techniques exist for bazel macros?

Tags: bazel

I found that adding a `print` statement to my bazel macros and rule implementations result in console output added to the build such as

```
DEBUG: /home/$USER/repo/source.bzl:82:5: message XYZ
```

And I can even introspect a bit of objects with standard python techniques like...

```py
def my_macro(my_list):
    print(my_list)
    print(type(my_list))
    print(dir(my_list))


DEBUG: /home/$USER/repo/source.bzl:83:5: ["//visibility:public"]
DEBUG: /home/$USER/repo/source.bzl:84:5: list
DEBUG: /home/$USER/repo/source.bzl:85:5: ["append", "extend", "index", "insert", "pop", "remove"]
```

Is there anyway to access things like in the traceback module to look at stack traces and what not? Maybe even something like importing pdb and setting a break point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lil section in the documentation dedicated to macro debugging

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/macros.html#debugging

> You can also use print for debugging.

Where the print function is explicitly pointed out a handy link is given which redirects you to the globals functions.

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/globals.html

There you can see the `type` and `dir` entries. Not seeing anything stack trace oriented just some techniques for probing the current call stack context.

---

Update

Some wisdom I've learned in the intervening period is to add delimiters the the debug output by printing section headers as well as the name passed in to the macro. This greatly helps because when the analysis phase executes you get prints for every target in the bazel package you're debugging within and things can get disorienting quick with a large volume of debug traces being printed out. Redirecting it all to a file and searching after the fact, perhaps with some reformatting of lists and other lengthy items, will go a long way in debugging macro snafus.

```py
print("==========================================")
print("target: " + name)
```

You're welcome to also print any other pertinent details for attribute values of interest.

Another handy output evaluator is to examine the full & complete build output passed down to a bazel rule. You can do so with a query command such as this...

`bazel query //projectX:target_foo --output build`

From there you can examine the net result from a rule being intantiated in a macro which gives its own perspective to a macro's work.